# Using QuickSort to sort months in calendar order

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

I am writing a program which needs to be capable of sorting weather data. One of the functionalities is that when sorting data by month, it has to sort months in order as they appear in calendar (if it's in ascending order, it has to be January, February, March and so on; not April, August, etc).

The problem I am having is that the algorithm (QuickSort) does not quite sort the array the way I want it to.

```
public static void sortMonths(string[] month,int left,int right)
{
    Dictionary<string,int> monthsDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>()
    {
        {"January",1},
        {"February",2},
        {"March",3},
        {"April",4},
        {"May", 5},
        {"June", 6},
        {"July", 7},
        {"August", 8},
        {"September", 9},
        {"October", 10},
        {"November", 11},
        {"December", 12},
    };

    int i = left,j = right;

    string[] sortedMonth = month;

    string tempMonth;

    string pivot = sortedMonth[(i+j)/2];

    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(monthsDictionary[sortedMonth[i]] < monthsDictionary[pivot])
            i++;
        while(monthsDictionary[sortedMonth[j]] > monthsDictionary[pivot])
            j--;
        if(i <= j)
        {
            tempMonth = sortedMonth[i];
            sortedMonth[i] = sortedMonth[j];
            sortedMonth[j] = tempMonth;

            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    if(left < j)
    {
        sortMonths(sortedMonth,left,j);
    }
    else if(i < right)
    {
        sortMonths(sortedMonth,i,right);
    }

    for(int ctr = 0;ctr < sortedMonth.Length; ctr++)
        Console.WriteLine(sortedMonth[ctr]);
}
```

I've heard that one way of approaching this task is using a dictionary to point names of the months to their equivalent number values, which is what I am doing, but it still doesn't seem to work. I just want to know what I am doing wrong and what should I do to fix this. Maybe there is a better solution to this task or a better algorithm I could use? Also, I am not allowed to use predefined sorting functions and the for loop at the end is just to see if the array is sorted okay.

Comment: I wouldn't use a dictionary for this task because of this:
"For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined." I would create a class that wraps the Months {name, value} and then instantiate an array of Month to do the sorting. string[] sortedMonth = month that variable is unnecesary in Quicksort.

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, but why you prints the result in each call?

Comment: Roberto De La Parra- How do I actually make that class you mentioned, may I ask?

Arturo Menchaca- I do it because I want to make sure it's sorting the array correctly. I'll get rid of that for loop after I finish building this algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert your months to integers. You want an `int[]`.
2. Sort the `int[]`.
3. Convert the `int[]` back to a `string[]` (month names).
4. Overwrite all the values in the original `month` array with the sorted ones.

Comment: But the months are strings, I mean, they are not numbers. Can you still convert them?

Comment: "January" -> 0, "February" -> 1, etc. Do you need example C# code for that? Hint: `int ConvertMonthStringToInt(string month) { switch (month) { ... } }`

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a shot.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is working correctly. Also, I've got rid of that for loop at the end of QuickSort, because it has been recursively printing the nonsense values, therefore, it was mistaken me greatly. But thanks for your help, I will put you down as a reference.